# How is it possible to run 2 Websites in 2 different subfolders on one Apache instance?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

i just want to run 2 web applications which both are in seperate subfolders.
So Subfolder One (which is the Homepage) should be reachable under : example.com.
While Subfolder two should be reachable under example.com/subfolder .

I know it is somehow possible with the Apache vhosts file, but i am new to this vhost stuff und dont know, how to solve that problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Read something about virtual hosts here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/name-based.html and then post your configuration and exactly what problems you might not be able to solve on your own. Stackoverflow is a community, where you can find solutions for exactly defined problems, when you show the code and also show the effort you put in solving the problem so far and the results you got.

Answer (score 0):

i just got it running like that! Is there any reason this could be a problem in sight of security?

```
        <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName example.com
            ServerAdmin example@mail.com
            Redirect permanent / https://example.com
    
            DocumentRoot /var/www/webpage/
            <Directory /var/www/webpage/>
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

**And for SSL**


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin example@mail.com
    ServerName example.com:443
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webpage/
    <Directory /var/www/webpage/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/webpage>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /subfolder /var/www/subfolder/
    <Directory /var/www/subfolder>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>


  SSLCertificateFile /etc/certs/live/**********/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certs/live/**********/privkey.pem
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
```